# Error setting up Cloud Storage terraform backend: "Error impersonate: status code 403: The caller does not have permission"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-storage, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to set-up a terraform remote backend using GCP Cloud Storage. I first created a service account from the CLI:

`gcloud iam service-accounts create $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME --display-name $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME`

And then added roles to it. From what I read in the Cloud Storage (GCS) docs, the `roles/storage.objectAdmin` role should give full rights over GCS objects:

`gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_ID --member serviceAccount:$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME@$PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role roles/storage.objectAdmin`

I have the following `main.tf` file:

```
terraform {
  required_version = "1.2.2"

  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "4.13.0"
    }
  }

  backend "gcs" {
  }

}

provider "google" {
  project = "project-sandbox"
  region  = "europe-west1"
  impersonate_service_account = "my-test-svc@project-sandbox.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

And here is my `remote.backend` file:

```
bucket = "my_example_sandbox_bucket_985gd5d"
prefix = "terraform/state"
impersonate_service_account = "my-test-svc@project-sandbox.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
```

However, when I run `terraform init -backend-config=remote.backend`, I get the following error:

```
Initializing the backend...
╷
│ Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: querying Cloud Storage failed: Get "https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/my_example_sandbox_bucket_985gd5d/o?alt=json&delimiter=%2F&pageToken=&prefix=terraform%2Fstate%2F&prettyPrint=false&projection=full&versions=false": impersonate: status code 403: {
│   "error": {
│     "code": 403,
│     "message": "The caller does not have permission",
│     "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
│   }
│ }
```

I tried to give my service account more roles such as `roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator` as the Terraform [docs](https://www.terraform.io/language/settings/backends/gcs#impersonate_service_account) on using GCS as backend state this is required. However, the error persists. Is there a problem in my terraform somewhere? Or is there a role that I am missing? I could try giving it the owner role but that seems a bit extreme given it should only be needed for writing files to the bucket.

Answer (score 4):

Please check the following:

1. The Organization Policy API needs to be enabled.
2. The Service Account needs to have an `Organization Policy Administrator` role at the organization level.
3. The Service Account User and Service Account Token Creator roles [should be assigned to the principal account to impersonate a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/impersonating-service-accounts#allow-impersonation).
4. Your `ADC` (Application Default Credentials) needs to be configured for the same user as your `terraform apply` user/organization. If not, you could run `gcloud auth application-default login` again and recreate the ADC with the right user.